# Probability of person A catching the bus

Tags: probability

Lets say a person and a bus arrive at the station at a random time between 07:00AM to 08:00AM.

The person will only get on the bus if he has to wait $\ 20 $ minutes or less.
What is the probability he will take the bus?
According to the book it is:

$$\ P(X-Y \le 20) = \frac{40\times20+19+ \ ... \ + 1}{60^2} = 0.275 $$

I really don't understand this computation?

Comment: the way the question is posed it is ill-defined - saying that these random variables are discrete between 0 and 59 doesn't specify their distribution.

Comment: yup badly written question.

Comment: Assuming the distribution was meant to be uniform:  these sort of problems tend to be easy once you draw a picture.  The joint distribution of $X,Y$ is described by the lattice points in a square of side $59$.  Now figure out which of those lattice points are "good".

Comment: Is it any better now?

Comment: @bm1125 The other commenters aren't fussing at you. They're fussing at the way the question was worded, and I think you were just repeating the question as originally worded, right?

Comment: To be honest , no. I actually translated it from my language. Taken a word by word it is actually more close to the edited version. I forget how much mathematicians emphasise Importance of correct wording. I'm just a sloppy student trying to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the person arrives between 7:00 and 7:39, there are $20$ times (for each minute) that the bus can arrive "in time." That's your $40\times20$.

If the person arrives at 7:40, there are $19$ times (7:41, 7:42, ... 7:59). That's your $19$.

If the person arrives at 7:41, there are $18$ times (7:42, 7:43, ... 7:59). That's your $18$.

And so forth up to the person arriving at 7:58. That's your $1$.

The denominator covers all pairs of arrival times for both person and bus.

Like other commenters said, this is a poorly-worded question (nothing you did), but this is one way to explain the answer.